# Odoo: Connect Bank Account

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am interested to know, is it possible to connect Odoo with Online Banking system?

Actually I am interested to connect my Bank Account with Odoo and do wire transfer.

Is there any existing module available which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can start trying this, go to `Settings/Configuration/Invoicing/Bank & Cash`, and there is `Configure your company bank accounts`, there are some other options like **Manage Payments Using Paypal,Manage Payments Using Ogone,Manage Payments Using Adyen, Manage Payments Using Buckaroo**, I never used it but, you don't miss nothing trying.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It isn't whether the module is exists or not.
The problem is that the bank company will never give you connection to Odoo.